# Cannot launch custom desktop app on gnome but it works fine with gtk-launch

Tags: linux, gtk, gnome

I install an application ([Ghidra](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra)) without .desktop file.

So I created one myself and placed it to `~/.local/share/applications/Ghidra.desktop`.

Gnome references it as an application in the `show applications`, but when I click on it, nothing happens.

So I tried to run `gtk-launch Ghidra` and it works fine this way.

this is my desktop file :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Ghidra
Comment=Launch Ghidra
Icon=/opt/ghidra/Ghidra.png
Exec=/opt/ghidra/ghidraRun
Terminal=false
Path=/opt/ghidra
Name[en_US]=Ghidra
```

Anyone knows the issue here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly this problem recently with another program, and was able to fix it by appending %u to the Exec key like so:

```
Exec=/path/to/program %u
```

This forwards a given URL to the program as parameter, as described [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.0.html#exec-variables).
I am not sure why this was needed in my case (as the program doesn't need any parameters to run) but it made it executable through Gnome.